# Draw.io : Why i can't print text on IE 11?

Tags: javascript, printing, internet-explorer-11, draw.io

Im tring to understand why I can't print text on  [draw.io](https://www.draw.io/) using Internet Explorer 11.

Basically what I do is creating a rectangle and double click on it to insert some text.
After that I go into [ File -> Print -> Preview ] , a new tab appears but the text is gone.

The debug shows nothing and there is no such error on Chrome , I really dont know what to do, hope someone can help me.

Comment: As Matthew mentions, this site is for programming questions. If you have an issue as a end user, better post to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/drawio

Comment: Better stack exchange site would be https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry, didn't know that. @David

Comment: I suggest you to check the answer and if you think that it is helpful to solve the issue than mark the answer and close the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is not a development issue, it is better if you consult the website developers for a user support.

As an alternative, you can try to add the site to the compatibility view settings.

[image]

After that it will show you the text in print preview.

[image]

Note that adding this site to compatibility view list may create other issues.

Other way is to Export your drawing as an image or PDF using the Export option from this site.

It will export the drawing as it is than you can try to print it. It may help to solve your issue.

This is the exported image.

[image]

Comment: Things only get worse with compatibility view settings. Draw.io doesn't even load.

Comment: Did you try to export the file as an image or PDF for printing? It is working fine without adding to compatibility view.

Comment: Yes i tried and it works, this method solve my problem ,a part of it , thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is a question suited for Stackoverflow as your best bet would be to contact the site developers.